# Jasper reports 508 compliance in pdf reports

Tags: jasper-reports

Are any one implemented American Disability Act compliance's (508 compliance's) in PDF reports using any Jasper Reporting tool ?

Appreciate help

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. You can add 508 compliance with tags, that will show in pdf report. Just right click on the title, for example, and te last options is "PDF Tags" -> Heading -> Heading 1 -> Full.